# Error when right clicked on Test Plan of JMeter after adding Jmeter Plugins

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

On JMeter , i added a plugin - JMeterPlugins-0.5.4.jar into "C:\Users\\Downloads\apache-jmeter-3.0\apache-jmeter-3.0\lib\ext"

After this, I restarted my JMeter.

Now when I right click on the Plan of JMeter, I get the following error. Any Ideas how to resolve it. Thank you.

### I know that if I remove the plugin it works. But I wanted to use - **Ultimate Threads.**

```
Uncaught Exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: kg.apc.jmeter.gui.GuiBuilderHelp
er.strechButtonToComponent(Ljavax/swing/JComponent;Ljavax/swing/JButton;)V. See
log file for details.
Uncaught Exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory.
```

---

Comment: Sorry for the Bold formatting in some lines. I dint mean it.

Comment: Use latest versions of the Plugins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version 0.5.4 seems a little bit outdated to me, looking into [releases history](http://jmeter-plugins.org/downloads/old/), it is 4 years old and assumed to be used with JMeter 2.7.

Please make sure you use the [latest stable version](http://jmeter-plugins.org/downloads/all/#Latest-Stable-Release) which is 1.4.0 at the moment.

I would also recommend using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager) in order to install and keep the plugins up-to-date.

Comment: Thank you Dmitri T, It worked. Thanks for all the Help.